In Python, want to find all the placemarks in a kml file, but the list is returning empty
Trying to find all the placemarks in a kml file, so I can alter them. But findall doesnt find any.
def scan (filename):
    from lxml import etree
    tree = etree.parse(open(filename,encoding='utf-8'))
    root = tree.getroot()   
    namespaces = {'kml': 'http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2'}
    placemarks = root.findall(".//{kml}Placemark", namespaces)
    for placemark in placemarks: 
        ##LIST IS EMPTY!!!
        name_text = placemark.findtext('.//name')
   return
#file structure is <kml><Document><Placemark><...></Placemark></Document></kml>
I seem unable gto post the actual kml file, keeps complaining its not proper code


Does this answer your question? Find Placemarks in kml file

Have a look at the fastkml documentation
from fastkml.utils import find_all
from fastkml import KML
from fastkml import Placemark
k = KML.parse("docs/Document-clean.kml")
placemarks = find_all(k, of_type=Placemark)
for p in placemarks:
    print(p.geometry)
    print(p.name)  

